# confused about .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, error-handling

I'm trying to set up server error handling using the .htaccess file. Here's the entirety of my .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /errors.html
ErrorDocument 404 /errors.html
ErrorDocument 405 /errors.html
ErrorDocument 408 /errors.html
ErrorDocument 500 /errors.html
ErrorDocument 502 /errors.html
ErrorDocument 504 /errors.html
```

the .htaccess file is in the root directory.

Problem is, this file isn't working at all. I get a server error when I type junk into the .htaccess file, but that's the only time I get a result. It's not redirecting to the errors.html page when I type in an errant URL

I don't know if this matters, but I'm using GoDaddy as my host, and through them have set the 404 error handling to my custom page.

PLEASE explain any answers or ideas you might have for this because I haven't really found anything that explains things well for .htaccess. Thanks!

Comment: What is your question?  What are you confused about?

Comment: Crap, sorry! I updated with the problem I'm having

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to do this for triadbarspecials.com which is the site listed in your profile here it will not work.  A review of triadbarspecials.com shows the error "Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in D:\Hosting\8274214\html\tracking\tracking.php on line 64" which indicates you are on a Windows hosting account.  The use of.htaccess files will only work on a Go Daddy Linux account.  You can migrate your hosting to a Linux account if you want to though.

**To Switch Your Hosting Account Operating System**

1. Log in to your Account Manager.
2. Click Web Hosting.
3. Click Options next to the account you want to use.
4. Go to the Customize tab.
5. From the Plan menu, select a new hosting plan.

   NOTE: If you do not see the Plan menu, contact customer support.
6. Click Save Changes or Checkout, and then complete your purchase.

This change may make take up to 72 hours depending on the size of the site, the number of databases and other factors that may increase the complexity of the migration. We recommend that you do not try to FTP to your hosting account during the migration. You will receive an email message when we complete your upgrade.

Comment: It's been a while since I actually looked at whether it was Windows or Linux, but it is in fact Windows. Thanks for saving the day!

Comment: Glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 2):

To set a custom 404 error page on GoDaddy hosting, follow their instructions:

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1

1. Log in to your Account Manager.
2. Click Web Hosting.
3. Next to the hosting account you want to use, click Launch.
4. In the Settings section of the Hosting Control Center, click the 404 Error Options icon.
5. To edit the 404 error page preference for your hosting account, select one of the error-page options.
6. Click Continue.
7. Review and verify your 404 error page preferences. If everything looks OK, click Submit.

Comment: I already have that set up. I need to be able to handle other server errors as well

Comment: One of a long list of problems with GoDaddy. Why can't they just support standard ways of doing things like everyone else does?

Answer (score 0):

I would also CHMOD 644, that could be the problem I guess.